# JXTreeTable - Weird cell rendering issue for certain Look and Feels

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, look-and-feel, swingx

So here's my problem. I have developed a plugin for intellij which contains a tool window, and a part of it contains a tabbed pane with a JXTreeTable like this

[image]

Looks great and works as expected until I start clicking on the rows. I'll explain the issue through screenshots.

1. Row selected

   [image]

   2. Move mouse pointer to next row

[image]

3. Select Next row

[image]

4. Repeat above procedure for the next couple of rows and I end with this!

[image]

urghh..*puke*

5. Now If I move my mouse pointer back up those again, The colors come back like magic!

[image]

Continue moving mouse back up along the rows..
[image]

6. Also at any point if my mouse pointer leaves the column..The view is back to normal again (except for the selected row of course)

[image]

My Look and Feel is `IntelliJ Dark Look and Feel - com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.IntelliJLaf` , which I found out using `System.out.println(UIManager.getLookAndFeel())`

If I change my look and feel programmatically to something else, This issue disappears. But i'm **not** in a position to alter the default look and feel so I have to fix this issue (or bug?).

I've used a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872492/how-to-change-the-look-and-feel-of-a-single-part-of-a-java-program) to apply a different look and feel just for my JXTreeTable view component, and it worked great until.. I open another project on a new window (this creates a new instance of my tool window for the new project) and the hack this time around works against me, setting the look and feel properly for the new project instance, but resetting the look and feel back to default for my first project instance

Oh and i'm using the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` for my treetable.

EDIT: I implemented a custom cell renderer for the treetable, setting it to transparent when not selected (like MadProgrammer suggested), but the issue is still there.

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends JLabel
        implements TreeCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

        if (selected){
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }else{
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setOpaque(false);
        }
        setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");


        return this;
    }


}
```

There is a slight change in the results now. lol

Compare with 4. above

[image]

EDIT 02:

So I decided to completely disable cell selection for my treetable using `treeTable.setFocusable(false)`. Well guess what? Now when I click on a row nothing happens. No cell selections or colour changes. But once I move my mouse pointer to the next row as shown above (step 2), yup same story over again. Looks like it's related to a mouse listener somewhere? idk.. This is driving me nuts. Some help would be highly appreciated!

EDIT 03:

This seems to be the LAF that's giving me trouble
`com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.darcula.DarculaLaf`

source: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/ui/laf/darcula/DarculaLaf.java

EDIT 04

So I gave up SwingX and tried to implement a JTreeTable component from scratch, to see if this would fix the issue. I managed to put together an implementation using online source code. The results are interesting.

[image]

As you can see the issue is still there but unlike before, it does not propagate from cell to cell. So basically, it only shows on the current selected cell.

Anyway, the implementation I used, contains a `MyTreeTable` class which extends a `JTreeTable` class. The complete source code can be found [here](https://github.com/santhosh-tekuri/MyBlog/tree/2a5281f4c4fd3577aa35785e387435c9149cc6bb/XMLViewer/src/santhosh)

If I instantiate `JTreeTable` instead of `MyTreeTable` the cell rendering issue disappears, but so does the collapse/expand feature of the `JTreeTable`. It basically turns into a flat tree. (useless!) So whatever that's causing the issue,

1. Is in the `MyTreeTable` class
2. Provides the collapse/expand behavior
       to the tree component

after a bit of debugging I narrowed it down to the following method. If I remove this method from the `MyTreeTable` class, I can't expand/collapse the treetable, once it's included the cell rendering issue comes back.

```
    public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, EventObject e){

    if(e instanceof MouseEvent){
        MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent)e;
        // If the modifiers are not 0 (or the left mouse button),
        // tree may try and toggle the selection, and table
        // will then try and toggle, resulting in the
        // selection remaining the same. To avoid this, we
        // only dispatch when the modifiers are 0 (or the left mouse
        // button).
        if(me.getModifiers()==0 ||
                me.getModifiers()==InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK){
            for(int counter = getColumnCount()-1; counter>= 0;
                counter--){
                if(getColumnClass(counter)== TreeTableModel.class){
                    MouseEvent newME = new MouseEvent
                            (tree, me.getID(),
                                    me.getWhen(), me.getModifiers(),
                                    me.getX()-getCellRect(0, counter, true).x,
                                    me.getY(), me.getClickCount(),
                                    me.isPopupTrigger());
                    tree.dispatchEvent(newME);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return super.editCellAt(row, column, e);
}
```

Anyway, this looks like a bug from the intellij side because it's look and feel specific and exists to some degree in both SwingX and a standard library JTreeTable implementation. So maybe i'm approaching this totally wrong. But still if there is a possible fix, please share your ideas. I need this issue sorted out. thanks

Comment: By default, `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` wants to be opaque, you might want set it transparent when not selected

Comment: @MadProgrammer Issue is still there. Implemented a custom cell renderer to reflect your suggestion. see edits above

Comment: @MadProgrammer there is/was bug, a few times commented by kleopatra

Comment: @mKorbel So there is no work-around for this without changing the look and feel?

Comment: @fsociety only a few L&Fs has own Renderer, have to check APIs, then result should be as is described in your question, 1. whats L&F there, there must be used Tree and Table renderer (isSelected, hasFocus)

Comment: @ mKorbel Here is the source code for the look and feel that's giving me trouble
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/ui/laf/IntelliJLaf.java what am i supposed to look for?

Comment: The above look and feel actually extends this class
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/ui/laf/darcula/DarculaLaf.java

Comment: @mKorbel I've edited the question with more info, any potential solution to this really frustrating issue?

Comment: @kleopatra If you've seen this post, any possible fix?